# The type or namespace name 'SessionStateAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am getting above error what can be the possible reasons for it ?

Comment: maybe you're missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: maybe you're missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put this on top
**using System.Web.Mvc;**

Comment: Make sure it is ASP.NET MVC **3**.